# Android - creating custom directory to store files

Tags: android, file, storage

In my app, I am intending to store user generated files in a custom directory (that I intend to create) within the user's SD card storage.

I am doing that using:

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + "AppName");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
appDirectory.mkdirs();
```

Would you recommend taking this approach? Will this folder and files persist if the user deletes my application?

Because, the Android documentation says:

> If you want to save files that are not specific to your application
>   and that should not be deleted when your application is uninstalled,
>   save them to one of the public directories on the external storage.
>   These directories lay at the root of the external storage, such as
>   Music/, Pictures/, Ringtones/, and others.

I would need the files to persist even if the user uninstalls the app, but I did not wanted to clutter an existing folder my adding my files there - I thought creating a separate folder would be better. I am targetting API v9 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a pretty good way to do it. I do it in a similar way, except I keep everything in the data folder, i.e. `sdcard/data/{packagename}`.

**Update:**

You shouldn't do it like that. Use `Environment.getDataDirectory()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@jeffreyveon , your solution worked for me . Wish I could comment , but less reputation

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File appDirectory = new File(path + "/" + "FolderName");  
                appDirectory.mkdirs();
```